# Modal label elements wrapping to newline in webkit browsers

Tags: css, safari, webkit, google-chrome, modal-dialog

I'm currently having a problem with CSS styles in Webkit browswers (Chrome 4.0.249.89 & safari 4.0.4) in which I have a modal window that has a list of labels, radio buttons and some more text describing the what each radio button does. The modal displays correctly in FF 3.5.7

Here's the html for inside the modal,

```
<div id="rta_top">
        <img src="pb_close_off.png" width="17" height="15" alt="Close this window" title="Close this window" id="rta_close" />
        <h2 class="rta">Report</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="pb_bottom">
            <div id="error_holder">
                <div id="error"></div>
            </div>
        <br />
        Please choose a reason for reporting this ad:

        <form action="submit.php" method="post" id="report_form">
            <fieldset>
                <br />
                <label for="incorrect_address">Wrong Address:</label>
                    <div class="report_ad_radio">
                        <input type="radio" id="incorrect_address" name="description" value="1" />
                    </div>                  
                    <div class="report_ad_text">
                        <label for="incorrect_address"> &nbsp; (Ad has wrong address).</label>
                    </div>
                <br />

                <label for="duplicate">Duplicate:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="duplicate" name="description" value="2" />
                </div>

                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="duplicate"> &nbsp; (Identical to another ad on-site).</label>
                </div>
                <br />

                <label for="mis_classified">Mis-Classified:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="mis_classified" name="description" value="3" />
                </div>
                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="mis_classified">&nbsp; (Ad is in the wrong section).</label>
                </div>
                <br />

                <label for="inaccurate">Inaccurate:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="inaccurate" name="description" value="4" />
                </div>
                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="inaccurate">&nbsp; (No longer available / price changed).</label>
                </div>
                <br />

                <label for="photos">Photo Issue:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="photos" name="description" value="5" />
                </div>
                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="photos">&nbsp; (Photos are inappropriate or do not belong to this ad).</label>
                </div>
                <br />

                <label for="spam">Spam:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="spam" name="description" value="6" />
                </div>
                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="spam">&nbsp; (Ad is spam/scam and is not exclusive).</label>
                </div>
                <br />

                <label for="other">Other:</label>
                <div class="report_ad_radio">
                    <input type="radio" id="other" name="description" value="7" />
                </div>
                <div class="report_ad_text">
                    <label for="other">&nbsp; (Other reason, please specify).</label>
                </div>
                <br />
                <br />

                <label for="more_info">More Info:</label>
                    <textarea id="information" name="information"></textarea>
                <br />
                <br />

            <div id="sending">
                    <div id="loader"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="submit_report_ad" value="1" />
                    <input type="image" src="/i/button_send_off.png" id="reply_button" name="submit_reply" value="Send &raquo;" />
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css for each element:

```
#rta_background {
    padding: 10px;
    background: url(/i/bg_modal_ra.png) no-repeat;
}

#ra_background_sent{
    padding: 10px;
    background: url(/i/bg_modal_ra_sent.png) no-repeat;
}

#rta_top {
    padding: 0 8px 0 18px;
    background: #355eae url(/i/bg_linkbar_off.png) repeat-x;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
}

#rta_top h2 {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 495px;
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #fff;
}

#rta_close {
    margin: 7px 0 0;
    float: right;
}

#rta #pb_bottom fieldset {
    background: #dff;
}

.report_ad_radio {
    padding: 5px 0 0 5px;
    float: left;
}

#rta #pb_bottom .rta_warning {
    margin: 0 auto 6px;
    border: 1px solid #f00;
    padding: 2px 0;
    width: 80%;
    height: 15px;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    text-align: center;
    background: #fdd;
}

#rta #pb_bottom  .report_ad_text {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#rta #pb_bottom .report_ad_text label {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    cursor: pointer;
    background: #00f000;
}

#information {
    margin: 5px 0 0 5px;
    padding: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
    width: 370px; 
    height: 76px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    color: #888;
    line-height: 1.4;
    resize: none;
}

#sending {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 24px;
}

#pb_bottom #error {
    margin: 0 20px 0 50px;
    height: 20px;
    width: 420px;
}

#loader {
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 6px;
    float:left;
}
```

In Safari it looks like this:

[Safari http://neilcremins.com/img_dump/modal-saf.png](http://neilcremins.com/img_dump/modal-saf.png)

In Firefox it looks like this:

[Firefox http://neilcremins.com/img_dump/modal-ff.png](http://neilcremins.com/img_dump/modal-ff.png)

Comment: @creminsn - what does "displays correctly" mean. What does it do in Firefox that it doesn't do in Webkit browsers? Can you narrow the problem down a bit? Can you reproduce it with a smaller chunk of code?

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply, I've edited the above post with images as to how to modal looks in safari and in firefox.

I think I've narrowed it down the the "sending" div, as removing that div and reloading displays the modal correctly like in firefox.

Comment: I was trying to recreate this, but looks like something is missing in your styles. The bold text is not bold and it is above the decription text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow.  Div-soup with everything defined in absolute measures.  I don't know where to start.  I know, I'll start here: you can only have one label per input, so... let's try this:

HTML:

```
<label><span class="intro">Wrong address</span><input type="radio" id="wrongaddress"/>(Ad has wrong address)</label>
```

CSS:

```
  label{display: block}
  .intro{width: 12em; float: left; font-weight: bold}
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/isoke).

Less is more.